Are funds sent into an address with IsOnCurve: false Retreivable?
I sent USDC to an address with IsOnCurve False, it was an exchange address. From what I have read, the funds are lost because nobody really has access to that address.
Then, I read here that there is a RecoverNested function, is this usable in my case? if so, who can send this instruction ?

If IsOnCurve is false, it means the address is a program-derived address. If an exchange has control of that address in their program, they can update their program to do anything with it, including retrieving the funds. There's no guarantee that the exchange will do that, though.
More info about program-derived addresses at https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/pdas.html#facts
